# trying to resolve missing file for dll .net app

Tags: esri

I inherited a .NET app using ArcGIS with next to know documentation and I'm just trying to get it up an running locally right now and I'm encountering some difficulties. I'm missing references to a few DLL's and was hoping someone could tell me which SDK(s) I needed to install to find them. I already have the standard .NET SDK v100.13 and I have the local server SDK v100.12  Here is a list of this missing DLL's that are being used:

> ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework
>
> ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF   (I know this one has been separated into ADF.Local
> and another binary)
>
> ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog
>
> ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls
>
> ESRI.ArcGIS.BaseClasses
>
> ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI

This app was made, I believe, in 2014 by a third party contracting company which no longer exists so I can't really reach out to them for any support. Are these DLL's from a deprecated SDK? Any help would be appreciated and if you need further information I will try my best to diligently respond, edit, and update my questions based on feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ArcObjects. Typically it is used to build customizations in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap, ArcCatalog). ArcObjects is also used with ArcGIS Engine to build stand-alone apps that include ArcGIS components. If it's an ArcGIS Desktop customization (e.g., add-in), then you would need to install ArcGIS Desktop, along with the ArcObjects SDK. If it's a stand-alone app, then the ArcGIS Engine Developer Kit. ArcObjects is not deprecated yet.